# Cocos2d-x label font color unable to set

Tags: label, cocos2d-x

```
        rect = Sprite::create();
        rect->setTextureRect(Rect(0, 0, 180, 80));

        rect->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height + 80));
        auto grad = LayerGradient::create(arr[randSayi][0], arr[randSayi][1]);
        grad->changeHeight(rect->getContentSize().height);
        grad->changeWidth(rect->getContentSize().width);

        label = Label::createWithTTF(arrRenk[randRenk], "fonts/font.ttf", 54);
        label->setPosition(rect->getContentSize().width / 2, rect->getContentSize().height / 2);
        label->setColor(/*(Color3B)arr[randSayi][0]*/Color3B(arr[randSayi][0]));
        grad->addChild(label);

        rect->setTag(i);
        rect->addChild(grad);
```

This is how i crete a rectangular sprite with a gradient color and a label added on top of it. My problem is that i can't set font color properly.

```
label->setColor(/*(Color3B)arr[randSayi][0]*/Color3B(arr[randSayi][0]));
```

arr[][] is an array of colors Color4B. I both tried casting and the uncommented out but the result is:

[image]

Which means color isn't set. Can anybody identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i tried in my code, both setColor and setTextColor work for me

my cocos2dx engine version is v3.2

you may take a try with setTextColor

Comment: i tried but it's not working. did you try the code identical to the code i shared?